# Space generated by vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a doubt: can you say, for sure, that every space generated by two linear independente vectors with two components generate $\mathbb{R^2}$?

For example: $L$ {$(1,1),(0,2)$} = $\mathbb{R^2}$

(which means that this type of vectors are always a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$)

Am I correct to admit this as always true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is $2$. So any two linearly independent vectors will always be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: But the vectors need to have only 2 components $(x,y)$ right?

Comment: Yes. But can you clarify what you mean by "need to have only two components"? What other configurations are you thinking of?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of having for example the space $L$ {$(1,1,2),(0,2,1)$}. This is indeed a space of dimension 2 but it isn't $\mathbb{R^2}$, right?

Comment: That isn't $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but the space $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: Exactly, same dimension! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help